# I think I'm misunderstanding Go polymorphism/interfaces/structs

Tags: go, struct, interface, polymorphism

I don't understand why the following code does not compile.

I am confused why Go is saying `HistoryReader` does not correctly implement `IReader`. `HistoryBook` implements `IBook`. Why are `Read(book Ibook)` and `Read(book HistoryBook)` not acceptable together when trying to add a `HistoryReader` to a slice of `IReader`s?

```
package main

type IReader interface {
   Read(book IBook)
}

// HistoryReader implements IReader
type HistoryReader struct{}

func (r *HistoryReader) Read(book HistoryBook) {
   // ...
}

type IBook interface{}

// HistoryBook implements IBook
type HistoryBook struct{}

func main() {
   var readerSlice []IReader

   _ = append(readerSlice, &HistoryReader{})
}
```

```
./main.go:28:26: cannot use &HistoryReader{} (value of type *HistoryReader) as type ReaderInterface in argument to append:
    *HistoryReader does not implement ReaderInterface (wrong type for Read method)
        have Read(book HistoryBook)
        want Read(book BookInterface)
```

Comment: HistoryBook is not just IBook, It can be more than IBook.
So instead of passing as HistoryBook, you can pass IBook and using 'cast type' inside the method.

Comment: 100% Duplicate. Asked each week. No contravariance in Go.

Answer (score 6):

`IReader` requires that `Read` takes any `IBook`.

But `HistoryReader.Read` only accepts a `HistoryBook`, not any `IBook`. Therefore, `HistoryReader` does not satisfy `IReader`.